# No puedo obtener un POST con express (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, promesas

Comence a desarrollar un pequeño cahtbot con tecnológia de IBM (Watson), estoy usando NodeJS para la parte del desarrollo de la aplicación. Estoy usando Express como Framework de enrutamiento, también he dividido el proyecto en vistas, rutas y el server. Me encontré con el siguiente error, tengo mi ruta como lo podemos ver:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();

        router.post('/conversation/', (req, res) => {
          const { text, context = {} } = req.body;

          const params = {
            input: { text },
            workspace_id:'Workspace-id',
            context,
          };

          assistant.message(params, (err, response) => {
            if (err) res.status(500).json(err);

            res.json(response);
          });
        });

module.exports = router;
```

Mi Server esta de la siguiente forma:

```
/*eslint-env node*/
'use strict';
// This application uses express as its web server
// for more info, see: http://expressjs.com
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');


// cfenv provides access to your Cloud Foundry environment
// for more info, see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv
const cfenv = require('cfenv');
// create a new express server
const app = express();

const AssistantV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/assistant/v1');

const assistant = new AssistantV1({
  username: 'username',
  password: 'pass',
  url: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/',
  version: '2018-02-16',
});

//Configuring the environment
//Use body-parser to nodejs understand the user requests
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//establish the views directory
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));  //__dirname get the main tab project
//establish the views engine
app.set('view engine','ejs');

// serve the files out of ./public as our main files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// get the app environment from Cloud Foundry
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

//Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));


// start server on the specified port and binding host
app.listen(appEnv.port, appEnv.bind, () => {
  // print a message when the server starts listening
  console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);

});
```

Ahora lo que quiero es iniciar mi server en el link **https://localhost:60001/conversation/**

cuando lo ingreso desde el navegador, obtengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

soy nuevo con NodeJS entonces, no sè que es lo que estoy haciendo mal, lo raro es que con el metodo GET no tengo el mismo problema y si me manda el render del index.ejs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estuve leyendo tu código. Al acceder a esa ruta mediante el navegador lo que está pasando es que se busca un GET no un POST como el que tienes. Para hacer peticiones POST, GET, DELETE, PUT etc. con parámetros y experimentar mas cosas te recomiendo que uses el software [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/) a mi me ha servido mucho.

Igual si quieres realizar peticiones mediante el URL utilizando GET, tendrás que definir una nueva ruta **router.get('/conversation/'...**

O hacer un petición POST en javascript, o mediante un FORM:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "tu_url");
xhr.send(parametros);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo!. Si he llegado a usar Postman en diferentes ocasiones, e incluso he hecho API REST pero con otro lenguaje, lo que no puedo comprender es; porque aquí o de esa forma que lo quiero, no puedo obtener mi método POST.

Comment: Porque al acceder mediante el URL estás accediendo al método GET, el cual no tienes definido, tendrías que hacer un AJAX  con método POST. Te agregué un ejemplo de POST en mi respuesta

Comment: Ok, perfecto, ya resolviste mi duda. Entonces veré como resolver esto con ajax, muchisimas gracìas!.